# Newest Twitter API to get followers handle

Tags: api, twitter

Using the latest Twitter API is there a way to get your followers handles? I don't know the correct term for this but I am referring to their name with that @ symbol. For example: @MyTwitterHandle

The code I am looking for would do this.

```
///Necessary Twitter Code
Outputs:

Your followers are:
1. @IFollowYou
2. @MyTwitterHandle
etc...
35k more followers etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do it is a two-step process:

1. Get all user IDs with [followers/ids](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids). This lets you get 5000 at a time.
2. Perform a [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup), which will give you the screen_name. This gives you 180 requests every 15 minutes for 100 users at a time.

This will take you about a half hour if everything is working well. The alternative, using followers/list, will take you over 3 hours because you only get 200 users in a 30 minute window (for app-only auth).

Comment: So forgive my ignorance but I put this in the url and it didn't work. i used the http and then api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=Obama&count=33

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have any links to the full code by chance? Still kind of new at this. If not I will keep looking. Thank you for your time and help so far.

Comment: There are 3rd party libraries that help with this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries - You might even find a familiar name in the list. :)